# limit character number for specific words starting with # in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, match

I have some issues, I need to "limit" character for specific word with special character  (10 characters)

**example in a textarea :**

The #dog is here, I need a #rest and this is not #availableeeeeeeee for now

the word "availableeeeeeeee" needs to be cut when I reach 10 characters

**Desired results**

The #dog is here, I need a #rest and this is not #availablee for now

My question is how to limit characters for each word that containing a hashtag?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Comment: There is a function called `.substr();` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think you can try the following.

Using [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method will cut the string in words, then [forEach](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp) word if it [startsWith](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp) a '#', we [substr](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) it up to 10 + 1 characters. Finally, [join](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) everybody to obtain the final result :).

```js
string="The #dog is here, I need a #rest and this is not #availableeeeeeeee for now"

var result = []
string.split(" ").forEach(function(item){ 
  if (item.startsWith("#")){ 
     result.push(item.substr(0,11));
  } else result.push(item);
});
console.log(result.join(" "));
```

Answer (score 3):

### 1. Regex Solution:

You can use **[`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method with the following regex [**`/(#\w{10})\[\w\d\]+/g`**](https://regex101.com/r/SqF2EN/2), it will remove the extra characters:

```
str = str.replace(/(#\w{10})[\w\d]+/g, '$1');
```

**Demo:**

```js
var str = "The #dog is here, I need a #rest and this is not #availableeeeeeeee for now";

str = str.replace(/(#\w{10})[\w\d]+/g, '$1');

console.log(str);
```

**Note:**

This regex matches the words starting with `#` using a matching group to get only the first 10 characters.

- Full match   `#availableeeeeeeee`
- Group 1. n/a `#availablee`

And the `.replace()` call will keep only the matched group from the regex and skip the extra characters.

Note that you need to attach this code in the `onchange` event handler of your textarea.

### 2. `split()` Solution:

If you want to go with a solution that doesn't use Regex, you can use `.split()` method with [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like this:

```
str = str.split(" ").map(function(item){ 
  return item.startsWith("#") && item.length > 11 ?  item.substr(0,11) : item;
}).join(" ");
```

**Demo:**

```js
var str = "The #dog is here, I need a #rest and this is not #availableeeeeeeee for now";

str = str.split(" ").map(function(item){ 
  return item.startsWith("#") && item.length > 11 ?  item.substr(0,11) : item;
}).join(" ");
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple solution with javascript could be, to split text area all words into array. iterate it and validate word length.

```
var value = $('#text').val();

 var maxSize = 10;
var words = value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ');

for(var wlength= 0 ; wlength < words.length; wlength++)
{
    if(words[wlength] > maxSize)
  {
  alert('size exceeds max allowed');
  }
}
```

you can try not allowing typing itself after 10 characters for any word by regular expression inline validation in HTML directly.